# How to append values in GoogleSheet using Python

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I am using the following codes:

```
wkpnl =sh.worksheet("PNL")

today=date.today()
d1 = today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
print(d1)
val1 = data['premium']
val2 = data['brokerage']  
print (val1,val2)
```

I want to append these 3 (date, val1 and val 2) values in GoogleSheet in A1,B1 and C1 using Python gspread every time I run python code automated add to next row. Gspread library is already installed and I am using the following code:

```
wkpnl.append_rows(pnldf.values.tolist(),value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")

But I am getting error, How to add said values in Googlesheet?
```

Answer (score 0):

For updating a specific cell, you can use:

```
wkpnl.update('A1', 'your_value')
```

For your problem, it seems that you want to update 3 cells on the same row. You can do the following: where the first argument is the row, the second argument is the column, the third argument is your value.

```
wkpnl.update(1, 3, 'your_value')
```

Read more [here](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/user-guide.html#updating-cells):

Comment: I want to append it so that every time fresh date, premium and brokerage updated row wise. Script will execute once after market closing on daily basis. Here premium and brokerage is amount generated through broker api. Please suggest.